# How to show datetime according to US timezone in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am new to MySQL query and stored-procedures. I am working from India and I want timezone for US. For that I am using

```
set currTimeStamp = date(UTC_TIMESTAMP + interval 5 hour + interval 30 minute);
set currDate = date(UTC_DATE() +  interval 5 hour + interval 30 minute);

-- insert into oc_product
insert into oc_product (model, ean, jan, isbn,mpn,location, stock_status_id,manufacturer_id,tax_class_id, date_available,
date_added,date_modified, image, weight, length, width, height, upc, price, sku, from_edi ) 
SELECT '','','','','','','','','',currDate, currTimeStamp , currTimeStamp , w.image, w.weight, w.length, w.width, 
w.height, w.upc, w.price, w.sku, 1 FROM tmp_product_insert as w left join oc_product as ocp on (ocp.sku <> w.sku 
and ocp.from_edi=1) where ocp.product_id IS NULL;
```

When I tried to print in local DB, it is showing

```
date(UTC_TIMESTAMP + interval 5 hour + interval 30 minute)
2020-07-13
```

but I want `2020-07-13 15:15:30` format.

For the `currTimeStamp` variable, we want `yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s` format and for the `currdate` variable we want `yyyy-mm-dd` format. How we can get this in the query?

Comment: Try `SELECT CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE(), 'system', '+5:30');`

Comment: ok i will try and let you know.
thanks for your time.

Comment: I tested and it is working fine. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `date` type you're using is explicitly **only** a date, with no time.  Use `datetime`.

Comment: SELECT date(DATETIME + interval 5 hour + interval 30 minute) FROM `oc_product`.     is it correct ....?